# What's the best solution to manage root password of thousands servers

Tags: linux, root, password

I'm a system administrator. In the production environment I need to manage thousands of servers. My colleagues and I uses a central manage server and distribute its public key through other servers. So we can use this manage server to ssh to other servers.

Sometimes we need to use the root password, for example when the server is down, we need to use iLO to determine the reason.

Currently, we uses a shared root password. It's unsafe. I also looked at some single server solution like `OPIE`(One-time Passwords In Everything), but since we have so many servers, this is not a very good idea.

EDIT:

What I want from the password manage solution is:

1. It should be safe, so One-time Password is a great solution.
2. The password can be easily entered, sometimes we need to attach monitor to server, or with iLO as I mentioned above.
3. The solution should work even the server is offline ( without any network connection )

So it's not a very good idea to set the root password to a long-and-random string, though it's generated from some known command ( like `openssl passwd` ). It's hard to remember, and sometimes it's hard to generate ( without my laptop around )

Comment: Are you already using a configuration management system like puppet?  What are you using?

Comment: Puppet++ for this.

Comment: We uses cfengine :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/) to push out the password change to all your servers. You would define `root` using the [`user` type](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/type.html#user) like so:

```
    user { 'root':
            ensure => present,
            password => '$1$blablah$blahblahblahblah',
    }
```

To generate the encrypted password:

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt "blah"
```

I'd suggest perhaps changing it every month or so---maybe using a scheme that your SAs memorized. You could also distribute it via a secure method or put it in a safe.

Answer (score 3):

You could always just set a disabled password.  This would prevent any network access to root, and if you boot into single user-mode most distributions will boot straight to a shell.

This probably isn't as big of a security issue as you might think it is.  It is trivial to bypass the root password anyway, unless you have locked down grub with a password, pretty much anyone could simply tell grub to start bash instead of initrd.

Of course this may mean, that you should instead be figuring out how to password protect your boot-loader instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one time passwords with a central management. 
I know, that this does not fit to "must work when eth is offline and server accessed with iLO".

Anyway: The question is, how often the server is offline.

So you could think of the following setup:

Use a centrally managed OTP solution like privacyidea (http://www.privacyidea.org). 
You can assign several different OTP tokens to the root user. Each token has a different OTP PIN and is a different device.
Thus all your colleagues can login as user root but in the audit log you will see which token authenticated, so you can know which colleague logged in at which time.

On the servers you need to configure pam_radius to pass the authentication request to the RADIUS and privacyIDEA.

Bummer. Now your server gets offline. In this case you should play with your pam stack. I could think of something like:

```
auth sufficient pam_unix.so
auth required pam_radius.so use_first_pass
```

So that you can login with a fixed password offline, and otherwise the password gets handed to pam_radius and is validated as OTP against privacyIDEA.

See this howto https://www.howtoforge.com/manage-two-factor-authentication-in-your-serverfarm-with-privacyidea.